# How to declare variable in angular2 with log=[{id: "Logs List Details1"},{id: "Logs List Details2"}....etc}] as dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

```
How to declare variable with  log=[{id: "Logs List Details1"},{id: "Logs List Details2"},....etc}] as dynamically. If i am giving statically like this and push my dynamic data to it, its taking after page limit over. But if i pass only one static value for log object and appending my data to it, its taking only one value. NO pagination happening in this condition. means my dynamic data is not appending here directly.Here My page limit per page is 3.

********here is my html code************

    <div class=" list-servers">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <span>Default Log</span>
        <span class="flt-right"><a href="#"><img src="images/plus.png">==</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="row-main">
      <div class="row">

       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9" id="content">

         <div class="content-area">
           <ng2-smart-table *ngIf="log" [settings]="settings" [source]="log" 
                  [defaultSettings]="defaultSettings" >
           </ng2-smart-table>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

**************And here is my .ts file***************
***********I am using Ng2-smart-table to display my log details.***********

    import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
    import any = jasmine.any;
    import {GetDefaultLogService} from '../get-default-log.service';
    import {DefaultLogItem} from '../default-log-item';
    import { OauthTokenService } from '../oauth-token.service';


    @Component({
     templateUrl: './get-default-log.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./get-default-log.component.css']
    })
    export class GetDefaultLogComponent implements OnInit{

     defaultLogItemValue: string;
     servername = sessionStorage.getItem("servername");
     logType = sessionStorage.getItem("logType");
     hidediv: boolean = true;

     settings = {
     columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'Logs List Details'
      }
     }
     };

    protected defaultSettings: Object  = {
      mode: 'inline', // inline|external|click-to-edit
      hideHeader: false,
      hideSubHeader: true,
      attr: {
        id: '',
      },
      noDataMessage: 'No data found',
      columns: {},
      pager: {
        display: true,
        perPage: 3
      }
    };

      defaultLogItems: DefaultLogItem[];

      // log:Array<any>=[{id: ""}];
      //log:any=[];
      //I want json in this format dynamically
      log=[
       {id: "Logs List Details1"},
       {id: "Logs List Details2"},
       {id: "Logs List Details3"},
       {id: "Logs List Details4"},
       {id: "Logs List Details5"}
      ];


  constructor(private service: GetDefaultLogService, private oauthTokenService: 
    OauthTokenService) {
        this.service.getLogItemList(this.oauthTokenService.getHeaders(), 
        sessionStorage.getItem("server"), 12345, 
        sessionStorage.getItem("startDate"), sessionStorage.getItem("endDate"), 
        sessionStorage.getItem("logType")).subscribe(lst =>{
          this.defaultLogItems = lst;
          for(var v in lst[0].logList) {
            this.log.push({id: lst[0].logList[v]});
          }

        });
    }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log("this.defaultLogItems"+this.log);
      }
    }
```

********So Please suggest with this.I am getting pagination but i do not want static data. And i want page limit Per page =10.

How to declare variable with  log=[{id: "Logs List Details1",id: "Logs List Details2"....etc}] as dynamically. If i am giving statically like this and push my dynamic data to it, its taking after page limit over. But if i pass only one static value for log object and appending my data to it, its taking only one value. NO pagination happening in this condition. means my dynamic data is not appending here directly

Answer (score 0):

Means you want to create array in following format:

```
log=[ 
    {id: "Logs List Details1"}, 
    {id: "Logs List Details2"}, 
    {id: "Logs List Details3"}, 
    {id: "Logs List Details4"}, 
    {id: "Logs List Details5"}
```

];

Try this

```
var log= [];
for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  let lg= {
   id:i
};
log.push(lg);
}
```

Comment: it's not working for me.Can you suggest me some other solution.

Comment: How to declare a variable to append data in this format dynamically log=[
     {id: "Logs List Details1"},
     {id: "Logs List Details2"},
    {id: "Logs List Details3"},
    {id: "Logs List Details4"},
    {id: "Logs List Details5"}
  ];
in angular2

Comment: here i am able to append after static data to the array like log = [] and display on UI but unable to add/append dynamic data directly from index zero. SO please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: @Vasantha, referred this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407618/angular-2-declaring-an-array-of-objects