# Creating Dummy Model In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I trying to create a dummy model in Angular to get values from back end. But it's throwing some error because of array.

**abc.ts**

```
export class abc {

    date: Date;
    time: string;
    ABC_Info: [{
            item: string,
            quantity: number,
            a: number
        },
        {
            item: string,
            quantity: number,
            a: number
        }
    ]

    constructor(date: Date, time: string, item: string, quantity: number, a: number) {
        this.meal_time = meal_time;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;

        this.ABC_Info[0].item = item;
        this.ABC_Info[0].quantity = quantity;
        this.ABC_Info[0].carbs = a;

        this.ABC_Info[1].item = item;
        this.ABC_Info[1].quantity = quantity;
        this.ABC_Info[1].carbs = a;

    }
}
```

**abc.service.ts**

```
import { abc} from './models/abc';

getABCs(start ? : moment.Moment, end ? : moment.Moment): Observable < abc[] > {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (start) {
        params = params.append('start', start.toISOString());
    }

    if (end) {
        params = params.append('end', end.toISOString());
    }
    return this.baseService.getParams('/api/abc/getAll', params)
        .pipe(
            map(res => res as Object[] || []),
            map(bolus => bolus.map(k => new abc(
                    new Date(k['date']),
                    k['time'],
                    k['item'],
                    k['quantity'],
                    k['a']))

            )
        )
}
```

**Error in browser console**

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at new
>   Bolus(abc.ts: 39) at abc.service.ts: 33 at Array.map( < anonymous > )
>   at MapSubscriber.project(carb.service.ts: 33) at MapSubscriber.push..
>   / node_modules / rxjs / _esm5 / internal / operators /
>   map.js.MapSubscriber._next(map.js: 35) at MapSubscriber.push.. /
>   node_modules / rxjs / _esm5 / internal /
>   Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next(Subscriber.js: 54) at
>   MapSubscriber.push.. / node_modules / rxjs / _esm5 / internal /
>   operators / map.js.MapSubscriber._next(map.js: 41) at
>   MapSubscriber.push.. / node_modules / rxjs / _esm5 / internal /
>   Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next(Subscriber.js: 54) at
>   MergeMapSubscriber.push.. / node_modules / rxjs / _esm5 / internal /
>   operators / mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext(mergeMap.js: 84)
>   at InnerSubscriber.push.. / node_modules / rxjs / _esm5 / internal /
>   InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next(InnerSubscriber.js: 15)

Comment: Dunno if it's really required by maybe add a `this.ABC_Info = [];` to initialize it as array. Maybe add the thrown error message to the question, might help.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: "I'm getting an error" is not helpful- it is necessary to explain what you are trying to do first.

Comment: I have shown my error take a look

Answer (score 1):

This is how to define a model:

```
export interface Abc {
  date: Date;
  time: string;
  ABC_Info: {item: string, quantity: number, a: number}[]
}
```

And then in your http service:

```
getAbc(): Observable<Abc> {
  return this.http.get('some api').pipe(map(res => res.json)); // Remove pipe if angular version is below 6
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :
[Angular 2 declaring an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407618/angular-2-declaring-an-array-of-objects)

It seems to me that you are trying to define a type for your array but also trying to create room for two objects, which is not how you should do it ( see the link ).

the error you have is because your array is not initialized when you try to access the 0 index ( check via console with a breakpoint, you will see that your array is undefined).