# How to declare list in Angular class?

Tags: angular

I have created username, password etc in an Angular class, I want to add list of roles in the same class, how can I add a list of roles?

```
export class User {
    userid: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    role: list;==> need to correct
}
```

Comment: what types are those roles? If they are strings, you can use array, like role: string[]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 declaring an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407618/angular-2-declaring-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list of roles are just strings then:

```
export class User {
    userId: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    role: string[];
}
```

If it is something a little more complex then you can use:

```
export class Role{
    id: number;
    type: string;
}

export class User {
    userId: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    role: Role[];
}
```

Your question lacks detail so any answers you will get will be limited.